# how can i refer to a local simpletype when using targetNamespace in my schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

how can i refer to the hex-integer simpletype when using targetNamespace - it works without
and i have no idea how to solve the problem, all the examples i've found do not use the targetNamespace attribute

schema/xml is tested with http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

my xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://foo.xsd">
<xs:simpleType name="hex-integer">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="0x[0-9a-fA-F]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="TheElements">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MyElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute type="hex-integer" name="TheValue" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MyOtherElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute type="hex-integer" name="TheOtherValue" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TheElements>
  <MyElement TheValue="0x20" />
  <MyOtherElement TheOtherValue="0x30" />
</TheElements>
```

UPDATE: based on forty-two answers i was able to parse some of the xml files
but found another problem with namespace-missuse in the xml files

Problem: I've got many simple/medium komplex xml files that i can't change but still want to schema-verify them

My Environment: C++, Xerces C++ 3.1.1

examples for the namespace miss-use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TheElements xmlns="">
  <MyElement TheValue="0x20" />
  <MyOtherElement TheOtherValue="0x30" />
</TheElements>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TheElements xmlns="http://foo.xsd">
  <MyElement TheValue="0x20" />
  <MyOtherElement TheOtherValue="0x30" />
</TheElements>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TheElements xmlns="http://foo.xsd">
  <MyElement xmlns="" TheValue="0x20" />
  <MyOtherElement TheOtherValue="0x30" />
</TheElements>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your XSD like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://foo.xsd" xmlns:tns="http://foo.xsd" >
<xs:simpleType name="hex-integer">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="0x[0-9a-fA-F]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="TheElements">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MyElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute type="tns:hex-integer" name="TheValue" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MyOtherElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute type="tns:hex-integer" name="TheOtherValue" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and you also need to declare the namespace in your instance document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TheElements xmlns="http://foo.xsd">
  <MyElement TheValue="0x20" />
  <MyOtherElement TheOtherValue="0x30" />
</TheElements>
```

Since the schema has the `targetNamespace="http://foo.xsd"`declaration, the global type definitions will belong to that namespace, and you must refer to them using that namespace.

Comment: is there any trick how i can get rid of the namespace in the xml-file? because i can't change the xml (the xml are from an disfunction "database" applikation that i want to convert) - but still want to do schema-validation

Comment: Then don't use any target namespace in your schema.

Comment: some xmls got xmlns="http://foo.xsd", some got only xmlns="" and others missing the xmlns-attribute  - any way to ignore the xmlns settings in the xml file - or better solution?

Comment: About the update: Not knowing your specific environment and tool set, but you could of course parse without being namespace aware, skip schema validation and do some "manual" validation

Comment: manual validation is possible - but it would cost time based on the amount of different simple/medium komplex xmls in my case

Comment: Last resort: Read each XML document into a DOM tree, strip it from every trace of namespace declarations and validate in memory against the schema *without* a target namespace